# Support Multiple Environments in Angular 9 with .net core 3.1 project

Tags: angular, .net-core, environment

There are two files by default in Environments environment.ts and environment.prod.ts in Angular.

I want to create new environment.qa.ts file and get configuration from them.

I am using Angular 9 with .net core 3.1.

Where to write code ? OR Do we need to change any code in startup.cs file  ?

Post some code.

Any help Appericiated.

Comment: what do you mean by support?, you want to create a new configuration?

Comment: @cabesuon Yes.i want to create 3 different configuration

Answer (score 1):

Just add the new environment file, in your case create `environment.qa.ts` in `environment` directory. Usually you can use `environment.ts` file as base file, and the modifications for the scenario.

After adding the new environment, you need to modify `angular.json` file accordingly. That will depend on what you want to achieve. Take a look that there is a `configuration` part in each `architect` command. For this, `production` configuration can guide you.

Comment: Can you post some code,I tried chnaging in angular.json file but this may be work with angular cli but this is project of .net core with Angular so is anything to write in startup.cs file ?

Comment: It should not matter that is a core-net project, the angular project is a classic angular project. What are you trying to achieve with the new environment?.

Comment: I want to create different environments with my app like Dev,,qa,LAB,Prod. Appropriate key should take from different file for different environments.

Comment: Sorry I totally miss to follow this question .. I don't know if you solve it already .. My suggestion is to duplicate production environment to try .. For this duplicate file `environment.prod.ts` to `environment.prod2.ts`, and then do the same in `angular.json` , add the copy of `production` as `production2` in the `configuration` section .. Then run `ng build --configuration=production2` .. Let me know .. Sorry again for the delay respond

Comment: Thank you for your response. successfully I am able to run the project in different configuration. You need to set into three different configuration in .csproj file.

Comment: Ok I am glad you solve it, just one question .. Are you using `ng`, I mean angular cli?

Comment: No. No need to use Angular cli.just you need to set different configuration in project .csproj file.as it default shows prod configuration.Still if you need more inform than I will post some code.